# How can I get past this HTTP GET 404 error in java?

Tags: java, apache, http, google-places-api

I'm using [Apache HTTPClient 4.2](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) and am trying to make a [Google Places API query](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests), but having problems.

Here is a basic snippet to illustrate the issue:

```
  //Web API related
  String apiKey = "API_KEY"; 
  //search params
  String location = "51.527277,-0.128625";//lat,lon
  int rad = 500;
  String types = "food";
  String name  = "pret";

  String getURL = "/maps/api/place/search/json?location="+location+"&radius="+rad+"&types="+types+"&name="+name+"&sensor=false&key="+apiKey;
  HttpHost host = new HttpHost("maps.googleapis.com",443,"https");
  HttpGet get = new HttpGet(host.toURI() + getURL);
  System.out.println("using getRequestLine(): " + get.getRequestLine());
  System.out.println("using getURI(): " + get.getURI().toString());

  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager());
  try {
      HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
      System.out.println("response: " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
  } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("HttpClient: An error occurred- ");
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

This output I'm getting looks a bit like this (with the exception of API_KEY of course):

```
using getRequestLine(): GET https://maps.googleapis.com:443/maps/api/place/search/json?location=51.527277,-0.128625&radius=500&types=food&name=pret&sensor=false&key=API_KEY HTTP/1.1
using getURI(): https://maps.googleapis.com:443/maps/api/place/search/json?location=51.527277,-0.128625&radius=500&types=food&name=pret&sensor=false&key=API_KEY
response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

It's all bit puzzling because:

1. I don't have a lot experience with HTTP REST calls
2. If I try the getRequestLine() url in the [Simple REST Client Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb) I get a status 200 with data looking like this:

   {
      "html_attributions" : [],
      "results" : [],
      "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
   }

but if I use the getURI() version it works fine.

I'm not sure if the problem is the "HTTP/1.1" that gets appended or something else.
Is this the proper way to make a Google Places API query from Java ?

Comment: It's complaining that https://maps.googleapis.com:443/maps/api/place/search/json does not exist. Which is odd, since I can browse to it.

Comment: You need to replace "API_KEY" with the actual api key.

Comment: Do you by any chance live in 16 Flaxman Terrace, London?

Comment: @Hidde Nope, I study at UCL near Euston, so I just some random nearby coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building the URL manually like that could cause your code to not escape the API key correctly and also you don't need to add the 433 if the host is HTTPS on the HTTP client, here's some code that works:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIUtils;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class GooglePlacesRequest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Web API related
        String apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE";
        // search params
        String location = "51.527277,-0.128625";// lat,lon
        String types = "food";
        String name = "pret";

        List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", location));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("radius", "500"));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("types", types));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sensor", "false"));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", apiKey));

        URL url = new URL(
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json");
        URI finalURI = URIUtils.createURI(
                url.getProtocol(), 
                url.getHost(),
                url.getPort(), 
                url.getPath(),
                URLEncodedUtils.format(parameters, "UTF-8"), 
                null);

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(finalURI);
        System.out.println("using getRequestLine(): " + get.getRequestLine());
        System.out.println("using getURI(): " + get.getURI().toString());

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager());
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
            System.out.println("response: "
                    + response.getStatusLine().toString());
            System.out.println( "Response content is:" );
            System.out.println( EntityUtils.toString( response.getEntity() ) );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("HttpClient: An error occurred- ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```